# Resize images of every size to fixed width and height

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

I tried a lot of methods to do that, but I still have a lot of troubles with that.

Is it possible to resize all images to fixed width and height?

I want every uploaded image with `width>=200px` and `height>=260px` to be resized to `width=200px` and `height=260px`, but I want to keep a bit of proportionality and if image is bigger than `200x260px` to resize it proportionally and then to capture center of image `200x260px`.

I just need idea to know where to start and what to do, but if you have an example I would like to see it. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the methods you've tried, and where you got stuck

Comment: Why don't you just set the width to 200 and set the height to "auto"? Did you try that?

Comment: @itsols what if image is 500x1500 of if image is 1000x200?

Comment: @MichaelRobinson i'm stuck in mathematical calculation of resized image width and height and how to capture center of image. (I can't find right formulas to calculate size)

Comment: @John check this out may be that help you http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/resizing/

Comment: So what you do is this - First using php, check if the image height is larger or the width. Then set the larger side to 200 and the other side to 'auto'. This should do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to trim the image you can do in the following way:-

```
//Your Image
$imgSrc = "image.jpg";

//getting the image dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

//saving the image into memory (for manipulation with GD Library)
$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);

// calculating the part of the image to use for thumbnail
if ($width > $height) {
  $y = 0;
  $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $height;
} else {
  $x = 0;
  $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $width;
}

// copying the part into thumbnail
$thumbSize = 100;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize,        $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

//final output
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Answer (score -1):

To begin writing the function, we have to declare it as such… Then we have to throw in our attributes. We want to restrict our image, so we have to let the function know the dimensions to which we want to restrict it, and we have to know what the original image size is to begin with (we’ll get to that part in a second).

```
<?php
function imageResize($width, $height, $target) {
//takes the larger size of the width and height and applies the
formula accordingly...this is so this script will work
dynamically with any size image
if ($width > $height) {
$percentage = ($target / $width);
} else {
$percentage = ($target / $height);
}
//gets the new value and applies the percentage, then rounds the value
$width = round($width * $percentage);
$height = round($height * $percentage);
//returns the new sizes in html image tag format...this is so you
can plug this function inside an image tag and just get the
return "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";
}
?>
```

Before we take our new function on a test drive, we need to get the width and height of the image that we want to display. There is a magical command in PHP called getimagesize(). This command, used properly, will return the image width, height, type, and even the width and height in HTML image tag format (width=”x” height=”y”).

```
$mysock = getimagesize("images/sock001.jpg");
```

Now, $mysock is an array that holds vital information about the particular image we want to display. In index 0, we have the width ($mysock[0]), and in index 1, we have the height ($mysock[1]). That’s really all we need, in order to get what we want done. Want to see the function… well, function? Here we go!

Let’s say you want to display a list of your beautiful socks, but you want room on the page to show them neatly in a row, and to do that they cannot be larger than 150 pixels tall or wide.

```
<?php
//get the image size of the picture and load it into an array
$mysock = getimagesize("images/sock001.jpg");
?>
<!-using a standard html image tag, where you would have the
width and height, insert your new imageResize() function with
the correct attributes -->

<img src="images/sock001.jpg" <?php imageResize($mysock[0],
$mysock[1], 150); ?>>
```

That’s it! Now, no matter what the original file size, it will be restricted to no more than 150 pixels in width or height (or whatever you specify).

Comment: But as the OP said in a comment above, what if the image uploaded is 5000 pixels wide? All you're doing is resizing the *display* width rather than generating a cropped version of the original image. That will slow the page down for users as they'll be downloading a 2mb image when a 5k one would suffice.